# AngularJS: Editar item de un Table en un Modal

Tags: angularjs, materialize

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto pequeño con una back-end Java y front-end con AngularJS y Materialize.

Ya tengo todo el back-end funcionando (probado con Rest-client), el problema que tengo en este momento es el siguiente:

Tengo un grid de datos, en donde para cada item se muestran las opciones Editar y Eliminar, como muestro a continuación: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para la opción Editar, la idea es que el item seleccionado se cargue en un Modal y desde allí realizar las modificaciones (típico caso).

Tengo codificado lo siguiente para tal efecto, pero tengo las siguientes observaciones:

El objeto seleccionado se carga en el controlador correctamente

1. El item (objeto) seleccionado se carga correctamente en el controlador
2. El modal no carga ni con `<a></a>` ni con `<button></button>`

**Columna de opciones en la tabla** (Eliminar funciona correctamente, pero sé que pasará lo mismo cuando quiera mostrar un dialogo de confirmación)

```
<tr ng-repeat="pln in plannings">
    ...
<td>
    <a href="#edit_modal" ng-click="editar(pln)" class="modal-trigger"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
    <a href="" ng-click="eliminar(pln.alertId)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
</td>
```

**Controller** en el controlador el objeto llega correctamente, el alert muestra el atributo con sus datos

```
$scope.editar = function(planningObj) {
    alert(planningObj.alertSqlQuery);
    $scope.sqlQuery = planningObj.alertSqlQuery;
}
```

**El Modal** lo estoy definiendo así

```
<div id="edit_modal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
```

De manera que el id del modal corresponde con el href si uso `<a></a>` o con el atributo `data-target` si uso `<button></button>`

Y tal como lo dice la documentación de [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/modals.html), inicializo el evento trigger así:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
        dismissible : false, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
        opacity : .5, // Opacity of modal background
        in_duration : 300, // Transition in duration
        out_duration : 200
    });
});
```

El problema en concreto es que el Modal no carga, no se muestra, no aparece. Siento que he seguido los pasos sugeridos según la documentación de Materialize, pero a lo mejor me falta algún detalle con AngularJS, ya que en otra ubicación de la aplicación (Agregar registros) si se muestra el modal correctamente.

**EDIT**

Bueno, tal como me lo recomendó @devconcept le di un vistazo a [angular-materialize](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/), y siguiendo las indicaciones que provee la documentación ha funcionado!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he eliminado de mi JavaScript todas las llamadas a `$document.ready` que las tenía colocadas porque en la documentación de [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) son requisito para que el componente funcione adecuadamente, pero con el uso de `angular-materialize` ya no son necesarias.

Mi línea en específico pasó de ser esto:

```
<a href="#edit_modal" ng-click="editar(pln)" class="modal-trigger">
```

a esto:

```
<a href="#edit_modal" ng-click="editar(pln)" modal>
```

solo fué cuestión de añadir la directiva `modal`

Ya con esto resuelto, queda por ver qué otra cosa puede salir. Mientras me pongo a ello, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: En las otras ubicaciones que mencionas, ¿lo estás haciendo de la misma forma?, ¿ves algún error en la consola del explorador?

Comment: Si, la única diferencia que veo es que; en este escenario que no funciona, la llamada se hace dentro de un `ng-repeat`, me intriga eso.

Comment: Para descartar algunas cosas, una vez que haya cargado la página por completo intenta ejecutar el trigger desde la consola: `$('.modal-trigger').leanModal(..)`, luego prueba haciendo click a alguno

Comment: Creo que despues de buscar algunas cosas podrías intentar usar el servicio [`$document`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) desde tu controlador, por lo menos creo que esta sería la forma mas Angularesca, es decir, `$document.ready(function() { ... })` dentro de tu controlador en vez de hacerlo en el template

Answer (score 3):

Estas enfocando mal la solución de tu problema. En angular no hay necesidad de llamar a `$document.ready` o `$(document).ready` ya que el framework tiene su propio proceso de inicialización usando `angular.bootstrap` o `ng-app`

> Angular initializes automatically upon DOMContentLoaded event or when the angular.js script is evaluated if at that time document.readyState is set to 'complete'

O sea que el framework esperará que todos los scripts carguen para ejecutar el código de tu applicacion (controllers, factories, etc).

Cuando te encuentres un caso como el tuyo es un claro síntoma que debes usar servicios y/o directivas para hacer funcionar los plugins de terceros que quieres usar. En tu caso yo existe uno en http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/ y trae soporte para [modals](http://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/#modals)

```
<tr ng-repeat="pln in plannings">
    ...
    <td>
    <a href="#edit_modal" ng-click="editar(pln)" modal><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
```

Usando la directiva `modal` puedes crear un modal trigger y el html del modal debes estructurarlo igual que siempre.

Comment: Vale, lo reviso y te comento. Parece interesante. Gracias!

Comment: Me ha funcionado de maravilla, gracias. Sigo adelante a ver que más encuentro.

Comment: @RosendoRopher No olvides marcar la respuesta como [aceptada](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) si te ha resultado útil

Comment: desde ayer la marqué, saludos!